# Studying physics at undergraduate level: Prerequisites

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I have been really interested in physics for some time and also take active interest in quantum mechanics.
I would like to pursue physics as my undergrad major. 
What kind of prerequisites does one need to major in physics? (I am going to study physics in Japan and right now is not so good at maths cause I am learning Japanese only for the past 6 months and has been totally out of it. )

Comment: Hi Mustahid. Welcome to Phys.SE. Your question has been asked several times before. Have a look around on the site. I'm closing this as duplicate of our book recommendation post, not because it is an exact duplicate, but to guide you in the right direction.